# ProjectEuler 7. 10001st prime

Tags: python

By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13.

What is the 10 001st prime number?

```
k = 10001
b = 2
for i in range(2, 100000):
    if i % 2 != 0 and i % 3 != 0:
        b += 1
        if b == k:
            print(i)
```

I expect the output of 104743, but the actual output is 29999. Why?

If k will be 6, I get the output of 13 and it's correct. But if k will be 10001, I get 29999 and it's wrong.

Comment: Maybe because composite numbers can have factors other than 2 and 3?

Comment: Test Driven Development in a nutshell :P

Comment: For your debugging considerations, the smallest failing case is `k=10`, which should be 29 but which you say is 25 (which is not a prime). You similarly count 35, 49, and 55 as primes, even though they're 5*7, 7*7 and 5*11. Save yourself some trouble and write an `isPrime(n)` function that you can test independently on various primes and non-primes, that way you don't have to debug ten thousand iterations all at the same time.

Comment: You have to use Sieve of Eratosthenes or similar

Answer (score 0):

**answer python ProjectEuler problems 11**

```
def main():
    number_prime_to_find = 10001
    x = 2
    list_of_primes = []
    while(len(list_of_primes) < number_prime_to_find):
        if all(x % prime for prime in list_of_primes):
            list_of_primes.append(x)
        x += 1
    print('The answer is :' , list_of_primes[-1])
main()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This may work, but it doesn't explain _why_ it works. Could you add some explanation to help other users of the site coming here?

Answer (score -1):

Try this java code

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] arr = new int[10000000];
        for(int i=2;i<10000000;i++)
        {
            arr[i]=i;
        }
        for(int i=2;i<10000000;i++)
            for(int j=i+i;j<10000000;j+=i)
                arr[j]=0;

        int t = in.nextInt();
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
            int n = in.nextInt();
            int count=0;
            for(int j=2;j<10000000;j++)
            {
                if(arr[j]!=0)
                {
                    count++;
                    if(count==n)
                    {
                        System.out.println(j);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[see this](https://interviewquizandanswers.blogspot.com/2020/04/project-euler-7-10001st-prime.html)